# Error 404.15 when calling an Web API from from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am sending a post request to API, when the string value get large around 20000 characters, I get 404.15 error. If I set string to few characters then post request is successful.  To resolve this issue I searched the net and found multiple resolutions but I did not get it right. Specialy the following link [Send HTTP POST request in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/send-http-post-request-in-net).

So I am adding my code below and hoping someone can help me get this resolved

API Code

```
[Route("InsertData")]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST", "PUT")]
    public IActionResult InsertData(string Char_2000,string Char_1000)
    {
        try
        {
            returnAuthNumber = _myRepository.InsertData(Char_2000,
                                                            Char_1000,
                                                            
            if (returnAuthNumber == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Data could not loaded");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
            _logger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);
            return Problem(statusCode: 500,
                detail: ex.Message);
        }
        return Ok(returnAuthNumber);

    }
```

Client request to the api. I don't know how logically correct it is but it is working when string char are just few characters.

```
public bool Post<T>(Controller mvcContrllr, string postURLString, string getURLString, string authToken, Dictionary<string, string> param = null)
        {
            var token = authToken;
        var url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"] + this.BuildCompleteUri(postURLString, param);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, this.BuildCompleteUri(url, param));
        var client = new HttpClient();
            // client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalVariables.apiUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
            return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

**Update**
I have fixed the problem by following the advice from the members reply. Just adding the code so it can help others.
Basically, from client side I modified the post method to send complex type (class) instead of simple types in list of parameters.
On API, I modified the method to accept complex type instead of simple type.
Note that by default API method accepts simple types from query string and complex type from body [FromBody].

client side request

```
public List<T> Post<T>(Controller mvcContrllr, string postURLString, string getURLString, string authToken, MyClass myclass, Dictionary<string, string> param = null)
    {
        var token = authToken;
        var url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"] + postURLString;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        var urlParm = url;
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(urlParm, myClass).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            content.Wait();
            var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(content.Result);
            return items;
        }

        return null;

    }
```

API

```
    [Route("InsertTAData")]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST", "PUT")]
    public IActionResult InsertData([FromBody] Myclass myClass)
                                
    {
        try
        {
            returnAuthNumber = _myRepository.InsertData(myClass);               
            if (returnAuthNumber == null) throw new NullReferenceException("Data could not loaded");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
            _logger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);
            return Problem(statusCode: 500,
                detail: ex.Message);
        }
        return Ok(returnAuthNumber);
    }
```

Comment: If you send large data send it by using [FromBody] because, in querystring data has limitation once it exceed limit data would be lost.

Comment: The client app is ASP.NET MVC 4.8 the API is ASP.Net 6

Comment: @marc_s It will behave the same reagardless of technology because its uniform to web server. Thus, IIS throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am sending a post request to API, when the string value get large
> around 20000 characters, I get 404.15 error.

You are getting the expected error which means [404.15 Query String Too Long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/#overview) because we cannot send large data using querystring once it exeed the limit your data would be lost and encounter the error you are getting.

> To resolve this issue I searched the net and found multiple
> resolutions but I did not get it right.

The  element specifies limits on HTTP requests that are processed by the Web server. These limits include the maximum size of a request, the maximum URL length, and the maximum length for a query string. As you can see below:

[image]

**Solution:**

You may get many work around online but if you wouldn't point the root cause it may persist in longer operation. [Though you can configure  request limits in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/#how-to-edit-the-request-filtering-feature-settings-and-request-limits). But the exact solution would be by using [[FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#frombody-attribute) along with your class to submit your large data and it would work accordingly.

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/#overview)